# Python Error When insert one column into SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, database

I'm trying to insert data from one column DataFrame into a SQL Server table.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time as t
import random as r
import datetime as dt
import mysql.connector
import pyodbc 
import sqlalchemy as sal
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server = '*****'
database = '****'
username = '' 
password = ''


# --- define our connection string ---

sql = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};\
                    SERVER='+server+';\
                    DATABASE='+database+';\
                    Trusted_Connection =yes;')


# --- create the connection cursor ---
cursor = sql.cursor()

d = {
  'item':[  'None',
  'eurnzd',
  'gbpusd',
  'nzdchf',
  'cadchf',
  'xtiusd',
  'xtiusd']
 }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (item) VALUES(?)", 
                    (row.item)) 
    
sql.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I get this error:

> ProgrammingError
>
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> in 
> 40 for index, row in df.iterrows():
> 41         cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (item) VALUES(?)",
> ---> 42                         (row.item))  #----------Only this column causes problems
> 43
> 44
>
> ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=method', 'HY105')

Answer (score 0):

Solve this by change the column name from "item" to "Item"
maybe "item" its python saved word, not sure